# How to create Listview with two textview and one toggle Button?

Tags: android, listview, textview, togglebutton

I have created the listview with two textview as a name and phone no. and infront of this one toggle button. i should get name when i click on the toggle button. but it is giving error as

> '02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425): java.lang.ClassCastException:       android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at com.example.comparearray.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:85)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   02-17 06:49:53.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

the below is my code

```
 lvCountries = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);

OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View item, int position, long id) {

     ListView lView = (ListView) lv;

     SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lView.getAdapter();

     HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position);

     /** The clicked Item in the ListView */
     RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) item;

     /** Getting the toggle button corresponding to the clicked item */
    ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(1);


     String strStatus = "";
     if(tgl.isChecked()){
         tgl.setChecked(false);
         strStatus = "Off";
         status[position]=false;
     }else{
         tgl.setChecked(true);
         strStatus = "On";
         status[position]=true;
     }
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) hm.get("txt") + " : " + strStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

};

lvCountries.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

please help me,i am stuck here.

Comment: Are you sure that `rLayout.getChildAt(1);` gets you the `ToogleButton`?
It probably is `rLayout.getChildAt(2);`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line

```
ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(1);
```

to

```
ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(2);
```

**Note : If not works once clean your project and try again.**

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanx all of you,my toggle button is at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

it is clearly stating that you are trying to cast textview in toggle button so please check first the toggle position in your layout . There is textview on index 1 here `rLayout.getChildAt(1);` .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using static index to get `ToggleButton` from selected row layout use `instanceof` to check is View is `ToggleButton` or `TextView`:

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) arg1;
for (int index = 0; index < rLayout.getChildCount(); index++) {
     View view=rLayout.getChildAt(index);
     if(view instanceof ToggleButton){      
        ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton)view;       
         //... do task here...
        break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error says "TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ToggleButton", so, the method  " rLayout.getChildAt(1)" clearly not working for you.
you could set id in XML, then find it from your "rLayout".

Comment: How can i find the id from rLayout?

Comment: rLayout.findViewById(R.id.your_id)

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a TextView into a ToggleButton. The problem is in this line:

```
ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton) rLayout.getChildAt(1);
```

For some reason the child at 1 is a TextView and not the expected ToggleButton.

I encourage you to use `findViewById` instead of `getChildAt`, so you'll find them by id and not position in layout. It will avoid these kind of bugs related to order of widgets.